# Elasticsearch Delete By Query API: Curl is working but failing to achieve same using Python (requests)?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am making use of Delete By Query API to delete a bunch of documents. Below curl is working perfect:

```
POST /tom-access/doc/_delete_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "_id": [
        "xxxxx",
        "yyyyy"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Now, I want to make use of `requests` library in Python to achieve the same.

```
import requests,json

url = "http://elastic.tool.com:80/tom-access/doc/_delete_by_query"
headers = {"Content-type": "application/json", "Accept": "application/json", "Authorization": "Basic asdadsasdasdasd"}

data = {
        'query':{
                'terms':{
                        '_id':[
                                'xxxxx',
                                'yyyyy'
                        ]
                }
        }
}

try:
    r = requests.post(url,
                 headers=headers,
                 data=data,
                 verify=False)
except blablaaa

response_dict = r.json()
print(response_dict)
```

I am getting below error:

> {'error': {'root_cause': [{'type': 'json_parse_exception', 'reason':
>   "Unrecognized token 'query': was expecting ('true', 'false' or
>   'null')\n at [Source:
>   org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@bc04803; line:
>   1, column: 7]"}], 'type': 'json_parse_exception', 'reason':
>   "Unrecognized token 'query': was expecting ('true', 'false' or
>   'null')\n at [Source:
>   org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@bc04803; line:
>   1, column: 7]"}, 'status': 500}

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Isn't the `url` wrong?

Comment: I messed up when copying. That is not the issue. Updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should try using double quotes (`""`) in the `data` variable instead of single quotes (`''`). Also, convert the query using `json.dumps()`. 
Here is an example from https://marcobonzanini.com/2015/02/02/how-to-query-elasticsearch-with-python/, where it shows the use of the `requests` library:

```
def search(uri, term):
    """Simple Elasticsearch Query"""
    query = json.dumps({
        "query": {
            "match": {
                "content": term
            }
        }
    })
    response = requests.get(uri, data=query)
    results = json.loads(response.text)
    return results
```

There is also  the official elasticsearch client for python [elasticsearch-py](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/).

Answer (score 1):

you need to change the way you are firing the request from python.

so instead of,

```
r = requests.post(url,
                 headers=headers,
                 data=data,
                 verify=False)
```

try using,

```
r = requests.post(url,
                 headers=headers,
                 data=json.dumps(data),
                 verify=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

It complains you are not passing your data structure in JSON data format, so you need to dump it to JSON first. Also Python `requests` library have a short-cut for this, so you do not need to dump your variable into JSON with:

```
r = requests.post(url,
                 headers=headers,
                 data=json.dumps(data),
                 verify=False)
```

Instead you can just use `json=data` option like this:

```
r = requests.post(url,
                 headers=headers,
                 json=data,
                 verify=False)
```